# Disable chrome autofill on <ng-autocomplete

Tags: angular

I'm using an <ng-autocomplete for users to select their city, state, and zip. I tried to disable chrome's autofill using "autocomplete = "none" just like regular inputs, but it doesn't work, I think because this isn't an html input.

Is there a way to disable chrome's autofill on this field?

My code:

```
<ng-autocomplete
  [data]="countryObject"
  [searchKeyword]="keyword"
  [initialValue]="initialVal"
  placeholder="Search Country"
  (selected)="selectEvent($event)"
  (inputChanged)='onChangeSearch($event)'
  (inputFocused)='onFocused($event)'
  [itemTemplate]="itemTemplate"
  [notFoundTemplate]="notFoundTemplate"
  formControlName="country"
  [ngClass]="{ 'is-invalid': submitted && f.country.errors }"
  required
  >
</ng-autocomplete>
```

Comment: Try this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52139123/is-there-a-way-to-disable-chrome-autofill-option-for-angular-form-fields

Comment: @AlbertoValerio tried that and it does not work, only works on my <input> fields not my <ng-autocomplete>

Answer (score 1):

Generally to disable the autofill of Chrome the `autocomplete` and `name` html attributes of the `<input>` should be set to a generated random string value. (Or at least for me this was the only working solution to get rid of the autofill.)

I just played around a little bit with the `ng-autocomplete` on this stackblitz:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ng-autocomplete

Unfortunatelly I did not find any possibility to overwrite the `autocomplete` and `name` html attributes through Angular parameters. I also posted a question about it here: https://github.com/sengirab/ngAutocomplete/issues/39

So now I guess there is no better way, than accessing the `nativeElement` of `ng-autocomplete` from a component/directive code, find the `<input>` inside it and update the above written attribute values to a generated random string. (The string needs to be different every time the site is loaded, this is why it needs to be generated.)

Comment: `[historyIdentifier]="null"`?

Comment: Setting `historyIdentifier="null"` does not influence the `autocomplete="off"` value of the `<input>` element inside. Or did you make it with this parameter?

Comment: make "historyIdentifier" to null makes that the ng-autocomplete don't show the last selected values in the component (don't store in localstore anything)  I think that @Dada asked about this

Comment: The question is about disabling the autofill of chrome.